# Hive - Split and count values by delimiter - lateral view explode

Tags: sql, csv, group-by, hive, count

I have a following Hive table

```
CustID    item_val

 10        sb1|sb2  
 11        sb2|sb3
 12        sb1|sb4
 13        sb2|sb3|sb5
 14        None
 15        sb1
```

I need to split and get the count values of each item in item_val column

Expected output

```
Item   count
sb1     3
sb2     2
sb3     2
sb4     1
sb5     1
None    1
```

I tired below count but values are not getting delimited properly.

```
 SELECT msg, count(*) FROM (SELECT distinct split(item_val,'\\|') AS msg FROM hive_table) t GROUP BY msg;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive, one option is to use the `lateral view` syntax:

```
select item, count(*) cnt
from mytable 
lateral view explode(split(item_val, '|')) item_val as item  
group by item
```